# Jasmine Unit Testing errors using ng-select package

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have imported ng-select component (https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) into my angular app and does not throw any console errors when running the app, and works as expected. However it causes errors when running my angular unit tests using Jasmine.

I have imported the NgSelectModule into my app.module.ts file under the imports array, and I have also imported the NgSelectComponent into my configuration.component.spec.ts file via the declarations array:

```
import { NgSelectComponent } from '@ng-select/ng-select';

 describe('Test Configuration Component',
  () => {
    let component: ConfigurationComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ConfigurationComponent>;

    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ConfigurationComponent, NgSelectComponent],
        imports: [FormsModule],
        providers: [{ provide: APIService, useClass: APIServiceMock }, Helper]
      });

      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ConfigurationComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });
```

My unit test looks like the following:

```
  it('check that array of employees got binded to accounts', async () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let employeeAccounts = [
      { "employeeAccountId": 1, "employeeId": 1, "name": "Name", "descriptor": "descriptor", "street": "Street", "postcode": "postcode", "state": "VIC", "city": "Melb", "country": "AU", "phone": "3123", "MCC": "MCC" },
      { "employeeAccountId": 2, "employeeId": 1, "name": "Name2", "descriptor": "descriptor2", "street": "Street2", "postcode": "postcode2", "state": "VIC2", "city": "Melb2", "country": "AU2", "phone": "3123", "MCC": "MCC2" }];
      component.employeeAccounts = employeeAccounts;
      component.ngOnInit();
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.employeeAccounts[1]).toEqual(employeeAccounts[1]);
      });
    });
```

The HTML for ng-select in configuration component looks like the following:

```
<ng-select [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployeeAccountId" [items]="employeeAccounts" (change)="accountSelected()" [disabled]="isLoadingAccounts" [loading]="isLoadingAccounts" bindLabel="name" bindValue="employeeAccountId" placeholder="Please Select"></ng-select>
```

I have had to use an older version of ng-select (v 1.5.2) due to Angular 5 compability issues.

Unit Test Error:

```
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0) Test Configuration Component check that array of employees got binded to accounts FAILED
        Error: Template parse errors:
        Can't bind to 'virtualScroll' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-dropdown-panel'.
        1. If 'virtualScroll' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
        2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
        <ng-dropdown-panel *ngIf="isOpen"
            class="ng-dropdown-panel"
            [ERROR ->][virtualScroll]="virtualScroll"
            [bufferAmount]="bufferAmount"
            [appendTo]="appendTo"
        "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/NgSelectComponent.html@47:4
        Can't bind to 'bufferAmount' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-dropdown-panel'.
        1. If 'bufferAmount' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
        2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
            class="ng-dropdown-panel"
            [virtualScroll]="virtualScroll"
            [ERROR ->][bufferAmount]="bufferAmount"
            [appendTo]="appendTo"
            [position]="dropdownPosition"
        "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/NgSelectComponent.html@48:4
        Can't bind to 'appendTo' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-dropdown-panel'.
        1. If 'appendTo' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
        2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
            [virtualScroll]="virtualScroll"
            [bufferAmount]="bufferAmount"
            [ERROR ->][appendTo]="appendTo"
            [position]="dropdownPosition"
            [headerTemplate]="headerTemplate"
        "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/NgSelectComponent.html@49:4
        Can't bind to 'position' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-dropdown-panel'.
        1. If 'position' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
        2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
            [bufferAmount]="bufferAmount"
            [appendTo]="appendTo"
            [ERROR ->][position]="dropdownPosition"
            [headerTemplate]="headerTemplate"
            [footerTemplate]="footerTempl"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/NgSelectComponent.html@50:4
        Can't bind to 'headerTemplate' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-dropdown-panel'.
        1. If 'headerTemplate' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
        2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
            [appendTo]="appendTo"
            [position]="dropdownPosition"
            [ERROR ->][headerTemplate]="headerTemplate"
            [footerTemplate]="footerTemplate"
            [items]="itemsList.filter"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/NgSelectComponent.html@51:4
        Can't bind to 'footerTemplate' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-dropdown-panel'.
        1. If 'footerTemplate' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
        2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
            [position]="dropdownPosition"
            [headerTemplate]="headerTemplate"
            [ERROR ->][footerTemplate]="footerTemplate"
            [items]="itemsList.filteredItems"
            (update)="viewPortItems ="): ng:///DynamicTestModule/NgSelectComponent.html@52:4
        Can't bind to 'items' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-dropdown-panel'.
        1. If 'items' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
        2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
            [headerTemplate]="headerTemplate"
            [footerTemplate]="footerTemplate"
            [ERROR ->][items]="itemsList.filteredItems"
            (update)="viewPortItems = $event"
            (scrollToEnd)="scrollToEn"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/NgSelectComponent.html@53:4
        'ng-dropdown-panel' is not a known element:
        1. If 'ng-dropdown-panel' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
        2. If 'ng-dropdown-panel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
            </span>
        </div>
        [ERROR ->]<ng-dropdown-panel *ngIf="isOpen"
            class="ng-dropdown-panel"
            [virtualScroll]="virtualScroll"
        "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/NgSelectComponent.html@45:0
            at syntaxError node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:486:22)
            at TemplateParser.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:24674:1)
            at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34629:1)
            at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34604:1)
            at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34505:48
            at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
            at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34505:1)
            at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34393:1
            at Object.then node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:475:33)
            at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34391:1)
        Failed: Cannot read property 'detectChanges' of undefined
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'detectChanges' of undefined
            at Object.<anonymous> src/app/configuration/configuration.component.spec.ts:87:17)
            at step (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js:89:23)
            at Object.next (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js:70:53)
            at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js:64:71
            at new ZoneAwarePromise node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:891:1)
            at webpackJsonp../src/app/configuration/configuration.component.spec.ts.__awaiter (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js:60:12)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> src/app/configuration/configuration.component.spec.ts:86:66)
            at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:288:1)
            at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:1)
```

I believe it could be because the version of ng-select I am using does not import all the necessary dependencies, but then I am using the dropdown successfully on the front-end so I think it may be a separate issue.

Any help identifying the problem would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Add NgSelectModule to your imports, this fixed the error for me.

```
import {
 NgSelectModule
} from '@ng-select/ng-select';

describe('Test Configuration Component',
() => {
 let component: ConfigurationComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture < ConfigurationComponent > ;

 beforeEach(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [ConfigurationComponent],
     imports: [FormsModule, NgSelectModule],
     providers: [{
       provide: APIService,
       useClass: APIServiceMock
     }, Helper]
   });

   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ConfigurationComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
 });
```

Edit: formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same error and have not found a way to separately inject 'ng-dropdown-panel'. To get around this for testing you can set schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA] in your test bed to prevent this error from happening

Set up your test like below:

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

describe('TestComponent', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

beforeEach(async(() => {
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  declarations: [TestComponent, NgSelectComponent],
  providers: [],
  schemas:[NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
.compileComponents();
}));
```